# Error Validating and uploading App to iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, ios

This is driving me crazy.  I've tried searching for answers and nothing quite matches my problem.

I've successfully archived my app and need to upload it to iTunes Connect. Apple recommends Application Loader but first needs to be done in Xcode.  When I attempt to validate or Distribute the app in Xcode, I get an error saying "No Identities are available for signing"

I'm confused because I've wiped my certificates and profiles clean but I continue to get this message.  Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: At which step exactly do you get the error?

Comment: When you say you've "wiped" your certificates, I assume you reinstalled your developer and provisioning certificates. On your target build, under "build settings", under "code signing", you need to sign your distribution build. What are you signing it with?

Comment: When I say "wiped" I mean cleaned out my certificates and restarted with new ones. Long story short, My original computer for development died so a new one was necessary.

I am attempting to sign it with my distribution profile but if I do that now I get "No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates" which is totally false because I have the profiles installed in Keychain and in Xcode.

Comment: you should read apple documents on how to distribute your app http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting ALL dev profiles and recreating a single provisional profile for Distribution and Developing each. Xcode then selected the profiles automatically without me having to import them into Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

"No identities available for signing" can get frustrating. What you should do is regenerate your distribution certificate and profile, that should fix the issue.

If you need help regenerating: Download and open the new distribution certificate, which will store it in your keychain. Then, drag-and-drop the profile into your Xcode organizer. Next, your going to click on the project in the upper left (it has a blue icon next to it), that will bring up the projects info. There should be 2 tabs at the top of the screen, "Info" and "Build Settings". When you click on Build Settings, the option to change the code signing is about halfway down the screen. When I ran into this issue, I had to change every single one of the code signing options to iPhone Distribution. (It might not be necessary to change *every* field, but I did). You should be good to go after this, let me know if you have anymore issues.

Comment: When I switch everything to iPhone distribution and attempt to re-archive it, I get an error saying "No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates"

This is extremely frustrating because my organizer recognizes my developer and distribution profiles.  I already have one archive which when I select to validate, tells me there aren't any identities available to sign"

Comment: A few questions... Did you regenerate everything? If you did, you said that your organizer recognizes your profile, so it says "Valid Profile" to the right of the profile name, correct? Also, when you downloaded your new distribution certificate, did you double click it so that it opens in your keychain?

Comment: Yes to both of those questions. All my profiles(9 of them) say valid profile and my keychain access has the necessary certificates.  When I try to archive the app, it will tell me i've succeeded but nothing happens. No record in my organizer.  I have one existing archive of an app that says it cannot be used because it wasn't signed by an iPhone Distribution Certificate.